# running unit-tests after every successful compilation

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing

Consider Visual Studio C++ solution with a static lib project and a console app with unit-tests. App post-build step is `"$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)"` to run tests automatically on each successful compilation.

When compilation is successful but tests fail I want to debug them sometimes, so I need to run them from VS. The problem is if tests fail the build is considered failed also, and so VS refuses to run.

A not ideal solution is to enable an option
[image]

so when you try to run failed build you get

[image]

(the option is `on` by default but sooner or later everybody clicks on "Do not show this dialog again")

It's not ideal because it's confusing, it triggers build again (compilation is skipped as it was successful but tests are run again, and the option is global meaning it applies to all your projects even those that don't need it. It's certainly not a very big deal, just wonder if people have some clever hacks for this.

For example, C# projects build events have an option "When the build updates the project output" - perfect for unit-testing after each compilation.

The project is cross-platform, so VS testing framework is not applicable.

Comment: Why is the VS testing framework not applicable? You're asking for an inevitably platform-specific solution here (assuming you're not using MSBuild on other platforms).

Comment: @Sneftel: Unit-tests are cross-platform, we use Google Test for them. Majority of development happens on Windows in VS (I think it's quite popular setup). My knowledge of VS testing framework is limited, do you see how it can help here?

Comment: How about making unit test a separate project which depends on main project? If it's build fails the main project will be still marked as built.

Comment: @VTT: It already is: `a static lib project and a console app with unit-tests`

Comment: I mean you make another project that depends on this console application and actually runs tests.

Comment: @Gruffalo sure, just use a GoogleTest adapter. (Beware: there's a few of them out there.)

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/05/10/unit-testing-and-the-future-announcing-the-test-adapter-for-google-test/

Comment: @Sneftel: it's a manual action we need to remember about and keep in our memory cache! I'm asking about running unit-tests automatically after every successful compilation

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose to add "makefile project" (File -> Add-> New Project -> Visual C++ -> General -> Makefile project) that would consist of "run unit test" command. And make test app itself not containing self-run.

Then your entire solution would fail on test failure, but test itself would success.

Your situation is not usual, though. Typically, apart from test app, a solution would contain "useful work app", and then unit test would go to pre-build of "useful work app" (which would also have dependency on test app)